# Defining a dask array from already blocked data on gcs

Tags: dask

I want to create a 3d dask array from data that I have that is already chunked. My data consists of 216 blocks containing 1024x1024x1024 uint8 voxels each, each stored as a compressed hdf5 file with one key called data. Compressed, my data is only a few megabytes per block, but decompressed, it takes 1GB per block. Furthermore, my data is currently stored in Google Cloud storage (gcs), although I could potentially mirror it locally inside a container.

I thought the easiest way would be to use zarr, following these instructions (https://pangeo.io/data.html). Would xarray have to decompress my data before saving to zarr format? Would it have to shuffle data and try to communicate across blocks? Is there a lower level way of assembling a zarr from hdf5 blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few questions there, so I will try to be brief and hope that some edits can flesh out details I may have omitted.

You do not need to do anything in order to view your data as a single dask array, since you can reference the individual chunks as arrays (see [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#numpy-slicing)) and then use the stack/concatenate functions to build up into a single array. That does mean opening every file in the client, in order to read the meatadata, though.

Similarly, xarray has some functions for reading *sets of files*, where you should be able to assume consistency of dtype and dimensionality - please see their docs.

As far as zarr is concerned, you could use dask to create the set of files for you on GCS or not, and choose to use the same chunking scheme as the input - then there will be no shuffling. Since zarr is very simple to set up and understand, you could even create the zarr dataset yourself and write the chunks one-by-one without having to create the dask array up front from the zarr files. That would normally be via the zarr API, and writing a chunk of data does not require any change to the metadata file, so can be done in parallel. In theory, you could simply copy a block in, if you understood the low-level data representation (e.g., int64 in C-array layout); however, I don't know how likely it is that the exact same compression mechanism will be available in both the original hdf and zarr (see [here](https://numcodecs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registry.html)).